# How to build RUNAS /NETONLY functionality into a (C#/.NET/WinForms) program?

Tags: .net, sql-server, security, authentication, runas

Our workstations are not members of the domain our SQL Server is on.  (They're not actually on a domain at all - don't ask).

When we use SSMS or anything to connect to the SQL Server, we use RUNAS /NETONLY with DOMAIN\user.  Then we type in the password and it launches the program.  (RUNAS /NETONLY does not allow you to include the password in the batch file).

So I've got a .NET WinForms app which needs a SQL connection, and the users have to launch it by running a batch file which has the RUNAS /NETONLY command-line and then it launches the EXE.

If the user accidentally launches the EXE directly, it cannot connect to SQL Server.

Right-clicking on the app and using the "Run As..." option doesn't work (presumably because the workstation doesn't really know about the domain).

I'm looking for a way for the application to do the RUNAS /NETONLY functionality internally before it starts anything significant.

Please see this link for a description of how RUNAS /NETONLY works: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=32443204&threadid=32442982

I'm thinking I'm going to have to use `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` with `CreateProcessWithLogonW`

Comment: Since the eggheadcafe link no longer works, here's an alternative article: http://www.pseale.com/pretend-youre-on-the-domain-with-runas-netonly

Comment: Since we can't edit the anwser for now (too many pending edits) I will update the link to Microsoft's one 'for a description of how RUNAS /NETONLY work' : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gathered these useful links:

http://www.developmentnow.com/g/36_2006_3_0_0_725350/Need-help-with-impersonation-please-.htm

http://blrchen.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!572204F8C4F8A77A!251.entry

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201129141929/http://geekswithblogs.net/khanna/archive/2005/02/09/22430.aspx)

http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinzugec/archive/2008/06/03/use-runas-from-non-domain-computer.aspx

It turns out I'm going to have to use `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` with `CreateProcessWithLogonW`.  I'm going to see if I can have the program detect if it has been launched that way and if not, gather the domain credentials and launch itself.  That way there will only be one self-managing EXE.

Comment: I know this is really old, but the first two links (developmentnow.com & blrchen.spaces.live.com) are deaed.

Comment: @chrnola the last one as well is broken.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old thread, but it was very useful.  I have the exact same situation as Cade Roux, as I wanted /netonly style functionality.

**John Rasch's answer works with one small modification!!!**

Add the following constant (around line 102 for consistency):

```
private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
```

Then change the call to `LogonUser` to use `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` instead of `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`.

That's the *only* change I had to make to get this to work perfectly!!!  Thank you John and Cade!!!

Here's the modified code in full for ease of copy/pasting:

```
namespace Tools
{
    #region Using directives.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    using System;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// <summary>
    /// Impersonation of a user. Allows to execute code under another
    /// user context.
    /// Please note that the account that instantiates the Impersonator class
    /// needs to have the 'Act as part of operating system' privilege set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>   
    /// This class is based on the information in the Microsoft knowledge base
    /// article http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158
    /// 
    /// Encapsulate an instance into a using-directive like e.g.:
    /// 
    ///     ...
    ///     using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
    ///     {
    ///         ...
    ///         [code that executes under the new context]
    ///         ...
    ///     }
    ///     ...
    /// 
    /// Please contact the author Uwe Keim (mailto:uwe.keim@zeta-software.de)
    /// for questions regarding this class.
    /// </remarks>
    public class Impersonator :
        IDisposable
    {
        #region Public methods.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor. Starts the impersonation with the given credentials.
        /// Please note that the account that instantiates the Impersonator class
        /// needs to have the 'Act as part of operating system' privilege set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        public Impersonator(
            string userName,
            string domainName,
            string password)
        {
            ImpersonateValidUser(userName, domainName, password);
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable member.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UndoImpersonation();
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region P/Invoke.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
            string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(
            IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(
            IntPtr handle);

        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region Private member.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the actual impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        private void ImpersonateValidUser(
            string userName,
            string domain,
            string password)
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                if (RevertToSelf())
                {
                    if (LogonUser(
                        userName,
                        domain,
                        password,
                        LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                        ref token) != 0)
                    {
                        if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                            tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                            impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                }
                if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reverts the impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        private void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }
        }

        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! this is why I love Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 7):

I just did something similar to this using an `ImpersonationContext`. It's very intuitive to use and has worked perfectly for me.

To run as a different user, the syntax is:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
    // code that executes under the new context...
}
```

Here is the class:

```
namespace Tools
{
    #region Using directives.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    using System;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    #endregion

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /// <summary>
    /// Impersonation of a user. Allows to execute code under another
    /// user context.
    /// Please note that the account that instantiates the Impersonator class
    /// needs to have the 'Act as part of operating system' privilege set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>   
    /// This class is based on the information in the Microsoft knowledge base
    /// article http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158
    /// 
    /// Encapsulate an instance into a using-directive like e.g.:
    /// 
    ///     ...
    ///     using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
    ///     {
    ///         ...
    ///         [code that executes under the new context]
    ///         ...
    ///     }
    ///     ...
    /// 
    /// Please contact the author Uwe Keim (mailto:uwe.keim@zeta-software.de)
    /// for questions regarding this class.
    /// </remarks>
    public class Impersonator :
        IDisposable
    {
        #region Public methods.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor. Starts the impersonation with the given credentials.
        /// Please note that the account that instantiates the Impersonator class
        /// needs to have the 'Act as part of operating system' privilege set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        public Impersonator(
            string userName,
            string domainName,
            string password)
        {
            ImpersonateValidUser(userName, domainName, password);
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable member.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UndoImpersonation();
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region P/Invoke.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
            string lpszUserName,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int DuplicateToken(
            IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(
            IntPtr handle);

        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion

        #region Private member.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the actual impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userName">The name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="domainName">The domain name of the user to act as.</param>
        /// <param name="password">The password of the user to act as.</param>
        private void ImpersonateValidUser(
            string userName,
            string domain,
            string password)
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = null;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                if (RevertToSelf())
                {
                    if (LogonUser(
                        userName,
                        domain,
                        password,
                        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                        ref token) != 0)
                    {
                        if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                            tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                            impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(token);
                }
                if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reverts the impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        private void UndoImpersonation()
        {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }
        }

        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #endregion
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: I have used similar code in a custom installer - however the 'Act as part of operating system' right is very powerful and I got a lot of pushback from system admins in granting this to average users. YMMV of course

Comment: Well this code is only good for logging on locally - for remote access credentials (basically for just the SQL connection) you have to use the equivalent of the /NETONLY flag, I'm trying to nail it down right now.

Comment: This link kind of illustrates the difference: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=32443204&threadid=32442982 - I might need to create a new process.

Comment: A different logon type and provider may help: http://blogs.catalystss.com/blogs/jonathan_rupp/archive/2008/02/26/sometimes-impersonation-isn-t-enough.aspx.  In original scenario, the local machine was part of the same domain, so that solution may not work here.

Comment: @Jonathan - Great point, I was using this to pull event log data from remote machines on the same domain

Answer (score 3):

Using the very helpful answers here, I created the below simplified class which uses APIs that are also available in .NET Standard:

```
public class Impersonator
{
    [DllImport("ADVAPI32.DLL", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(
        string lpszUsername,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        out SafeAccessTokenHandle phToken);

    public void RunAs(string domain, string username, string password, Action action)
    {
        using (var accessToken = GetUserAccessToken(domain, username, password))
        {
            WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(accessToken, action);
        }
    }

    private SafeAccessTokenHandle GetUserAccessToken(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETONLY = 9;

        bool isLogonSuccessful = LogonUser(username, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NETONLY, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out var safeAccessTokenHandle);
        if (!isLogonSuccessful)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        return safeAccessTokenHandle;
    }
}
```

Here's how you use it:

```
_impersonator.RunAs(
    "DOMAIN",
    "Username",
    "Password",
    () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("code executed here runs as the specified user with /netonly");
    });
```

Comment: Yes, really nice works !!

Comment: maybe you should included: Impersonator _impersonator = new Impersonator();

Answer (score 2):

This code is part of an RunAs class that we use to launch an external process with elevated privleges. Passing null for username & password will prompt with the standard UAC warnings. When passing a value for the username and password you can actually launch the application elevated without the UAC prompt.

```
public static Process Elevated( string process, string args, string username, string password, string workingDirectory )
{
    if( process == null || process.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "process" );

    process = Path.GetFullPath( process );
    string domain = null;
    if( username != null )
        username = GetUsername( username, out domain );
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.UseShellExecute = false;
    info.Arguments = args;
    info.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory ?? Path.GetDirectoryName( process );
    info.FileName = process;
    info.Verb = "runas";
    info.UserName = username;
    info.Domain = domain;
    info.LoadUserProfile = true;
    if( password != null )
    {
        SecureString ss = new SecureString();
        foreach( char c in password )
            ss.AppendChar( c );
        info.Password = ss;
    }

    return Process.Start( info );
}

private static string GetUsername( string username, out string domain ) 
{
    SplitUserName( username, out username, out domain );

    if( domain == null && username.IndexOf( '@' ) < 0 )
        domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "USERDOMAIN" );
    return username;
}
```

Comment: The ProcessStartInfo (and therefore the Process.Start method) doesn't have any equivalent settings to RUNAS /NETONLY, where the network credentials are used only for the network connection, not for the local thread/process permissions.

Comment: Bummer...you may have to resort to PInvoke and CreateProcess.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can't just add a user for the app to sql server and then use sql authentication rather than windows authentication?

Comment: Nope.  And I do actually want users who access this control panel to be themselves.  It's like a control dashboard that shows a number of processes and allows users to trigger them, see results, etc.

Comment: My client wants all SQL users to authenticate via Windows Authentication. They say it's for auditing.

Comment: @WalterStabosz Then your client should join his computers to an Active Directory domain. If they've already done that, it's as simple as using the `Trusted_Connection` option in the connection string. The only other option is sometimes you can work around this by using scheduled tasks to assign the correct user to run the process.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The app users are in the same boat as OP `Our workstations are not members of the domain our SQL Server is on`. The only way I've been able to use `Trusted_Connection` from one of our off-domain workstations is with `runas /netonly` . The users are contractors that work for my client, their workstations are not connected to the client's domain, but they are given AD credentials on the client's domain. #big-multinational-IT

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core, `WindowsImpersonationContext` and `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()` are not available.

Here is a link to a similar solution for .NET Core. [WindowsImpersonationContext & Impersonate() not found in ASP.Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529121/windowsimpersonationcontext-impersonate-not-found-in-asp-core)