# Issues connecting to sql server from outside domain

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues connecting to sql server either through SSMS or my C# application.
One thing to note is that I am out of my work domain. But I have in the past worked from home before and didn't had any issues. Maybe once but I restarted and it worked. But it's not working today.
Microsoft SQL Server ERROR 2

Comment: How do you connect? SQL Server authentication or windows authentication? If windows auth you might need the [`/netonly`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2796045/73226) switch though of course the problem may be a firewall config change between you and the SQL Server.

Comment: The sql server is installed locally on my machine and the database is local as well. So I am not sure if pinging the sql server would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to fix it. Logged on to sql server configuration manager and under sql server services I noticed that all the services were stopped. Just started the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) manually and everything is back to normal. 
Thank you everyone for your time and input. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Establish whether the correct port is open and listening (TCP port 1433 by default) you may need to speak to your network administrator for this.

The SQL Server Browser Service may also need to be running.

If not the above then perhaps an authentication issue...

Comment: The SQL Server Browser Service only needs to be running if the instance of SQL is a named instance or not running on default ports.

Comment: The SQL server is installed locally on my computer, I don't think it's the issue regarding the correct port number