# PowerShell: invoke-sqlcmd with Get-Credential doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I've never seen a so easy script failing so royally:

```
$SQLServer = "localhost"
$cred = Get-Credential
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Credential $cred -Query "select @@version"
```

[image]

the phrase says `-Credentials` is not recognized:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'.
```

So what is the point to have `Get-Credential`?
I see a lot of examples on internet and they all use it this way.

**EDIT EXAMPLE:** why this code is working with `-Credential`? Because `-Credential` is inside a function?

```
function Pause ($Message="Press any key to continue..."){ 
    "" 
    Write-Host $Message 
    $null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") 
} 

function GetCompName{ 
    $SQLServer = Read-Host "Please enter a computer name or IP" 
    CheckHost 
} 

function CheckHost{ 
    $ping = gwmi Win32_PingStatus -filter "Address='$SQLServer'" 
    if($ping.StatusCode -eq 0){$pcip=$ping.ProtocolAddress; GetCollation} 
    else{Pause "Host $SQLServer down...Press any key to continue"; GetCompName} 
} 


function GetCollation {
    #Provide Database Name 
    $DatabaseName ="master"
    #Prompt for user credentials 
    $credential = Get-Credential

    $Query = "SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;  " 

    invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $credential  -Query $Query | Format-Table

}
#---------Start Main-------------- 
$SQLServer = $args[0] 
if($SQLServer){CheckHost} 
else{GetCompName}
```

Comment: there is a username and credential param.  if you look at this article this is what they used to do what you are asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154122/invoke-sqlcmd-with-different-credential

Comment: This seems really odd. If you run the code manually instead of calling the script, does it work then? When you run Get-Credential you should be promted to enter both the username and the password for the new credential object, are you promted for both?

Comment: @HenrikStanleyMortensen, I get prompted if `invoke-sqlcmd` and `Get-Credential` are inside a function. It's hilarious but outside a function they don't get executed. And more hilarious `-Credentials` seems not recognized

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue could be resulting from the fact that Microsoft has two versions of `Invoke-Sqlcmd`:

1. [The Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet) - **no** `-Credentials` parameter.
2. [The SqlServer module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) - `-Credentials` parameter **is** available.

Looked at a couple of your recent SO questions - looks like you have [the Database Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet) version of the cmdlet. The [the SqlServer module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) is not installed by default, [so you have to do it manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module). (there's a 'Note' section in previous hyperlink that *explains some of the history behind this issue*)

In a nutshell, run the following command to get the [the SqlServer module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps):

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber
```

Make sure to include the `-AllowClobber` switch. It's a dumb-installer, and if you leave off the switch it will download the ~24MB package and then fail because it's overwriting the database engine version.

Comment: As it was already installed I run `Update-Module -Name SqlServer` this fixed my issue

Comment: You like to `The Database Engine` is broken. It might be referring to sqlps cmdlets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps