# /NetOnly Impersonation of a domain user from a non-domain PC

Tags: .net, impersonation, process.start

I believe I've read all the relevant `Process.Start` impersonation questions - at least all I could find via Google, but I haven't found one that matches this situation (and 90% are re: ASP which is a whole different ballgame)

Scenario: We've got a little tool which uses the current users credentials to query AD, get a list of servers matching a search, connect to them over SMB and get a list of shares.

I've been asked to make it possible for this process to work when run on a machine not on the domain, using credentials of a domain user.

I've added a switch which will prompt for credentials onstartup and then Process.Start() the same executable using the appropriate credentials (to save someone learning `runas /netonly ...`).

This is giving me a couple of issues. The code I'm testing with is below...

```vb
Dim ProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo With {
        .Domain = dlgImpersonate.Domain,
        .UserName = dlgImpersonate.Username,
        .Password = dlgImpersonate.Password,
        .FileName = Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly.Location,
        .UseShellExecute = False}

Try
    Process.Start(ProcInfo)
    ShouldEnd = True
Catch ex As Exception
    'HandleException(ex)
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Impersonation failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
End Try
```

So... If I run the code on my machine (on the domain), I can impersonate anybody. There are some quirks around querying AD but that's a different issue.

If I run the code on a brand new machine (not on the domain) I get:

```vb
Win32Exception: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password
Stack:
    at Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    at Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
    ...My code
```

I wondered if the machine was simply unaware of the domain or how to authenticate against it so I then tried from a command prompt...

```vb
runas /netonly /user:MyDomain\MyUser Test.exe
```

And this works fine.

So... How can I track down why `Process.Start` isn't authenticating as I expect?

NB: The credentials are correct - I've even resorted to copying/pasting from notepad to sanity check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this link: http://codebetter.com/jameskovacs/2009/10/12/tip-how-to-run-programs-as-a-domain-user-from-a-non-domain-computer/

Basically, you use runas with /netonly. But you still need to type in the password manually. You could do /savecred to cache the creds.

Comment: Thanks very much, that very close to what I want. Obviously, I'd prefer not having to show a console but I may be able to work around that... Let me do some more reading.

Comment: That link is fantastic information. I can't believe this post is not upvoted more. And it should be marked as the answer as I have never found anything that comes close to this level of function for this purpose.

Comment: This got closer than anything else, so I'm going to accept. For future hunters, someone's managed to invoke this from C# via the Win32 API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11672293/156755 (you might want to include that in your answer). Thanks to @DarrenMB for drawing my attention back