# Cannot find type after installing package

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm getting this exception when I run a .NET CORE REST API project in Visual Studio.

It cannot find `System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext`, so I install `System.Security.Principal` from NuGet and still get the same error. If I look at the package, the type `Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext` is not there. Where can I find a package with this type? According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8) the type should be in the namespace.

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll but was not handled in user
>   code Could not load type
>   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext` is not available for .Net Core 3.1. In the [same link you shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?view=netframework-4.8) it says **.Net Framework 4.8**, if you try to switch to .Net Core using the upper left dropdown you'll see the message that this type is no available.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529121/windowsimpersonationcontext-impersonate-not-found-in-asp-core) question where they're talking about it. I hope it helps.